# global moran in spdep package in R

Tags: r, matrix, spdep

In function `moran` in `spdep` package, which `argument` is being related to the weight matrix (or distance matrix)?

```
moran(x, listw, n, S0, zero.policy=NULL, NAOK=FALSE)
```

I have a matrix `W2` which is the distance between some cities, I would like to know the matrix `W2` should be placed in which of the arguments of `moran` function.

Here is some information about `moran` function:
https://rdrr.io/rforge/spdep/man/moran.html

Answer (score 0):

The `listw` oject contains two elements `weights` and `neighbours`. Each is a list of the same length where each element of `neighbors` contains all of the `j` values for observation `i`. The element `weights` contains the spatial weight for every element in `neighbours`.

If you already have a matrix that you want to use you can use `spdep::mat2listw()`. However without a more reproducible example I can't be of much help.